# Why does open(1) not throw an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I accidentally wrote code that effectively did this:

```
with open(1) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

This did not throw an error on opening `1` (not a string, but an actual integer), and then hung on `for line in f`. What exactly is happening here, and why does the `open` not throw an exception?

Note: What I really wrote was `with open(filepath) as f:`, and due to a bug I accidentally set  `filepath` to an integer. I don't expect this to come up frequently, but I was surprised that I didn't get an error.

Comment: It did for me: `OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid`

Comment: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) - "...or an integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped."

Comment: @hippozhipos. Also on Windows, but I got `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`. Same problem, different wrapper